# Multiple backslashes are not shown in Video

Tags: ffmpeg

I want wo insert  the text `\ \ \ \ \ \ '` in a video. I escaped it to this

```
-loglevel debug -y -i "in.mp4" -vf "[in] drawtext=fontfile=C\\\:\\\\Windows\\\\Fonts\\\\ariblk.ttf: text=\\\\ \\\\ \\\\ \\\\ \\\\ \\\\ \\\': fontsize=32 [out]" "out.mp4"
```

The paths are read correctly, but no backslash is shown in the video. If I double the backslashes to `\\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ '` I get the result I want with `\ \ \ \ \ \ '`

```
-loglevel debug -y -i "in.mp4" -vf "[in] drawtext=fontfile=C\\\:\\\\Windows\\\\Fonts\\\\ariblk.ttf: text=\\\\\\\\ \\\\\\\\ \\\\\\\\ \\\\\\\\ \\\\\\\\ \\\\\\\\ \\\': fontsize=16 [out]" "out.mp4"
```

The example from [ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Notes-on-filtergraph-escaping) works.

Which escape rule do I neglect?

**Edit:**
Escaping the text to

```
text='\\\\ \\\\ \\\\ \\\\ \\\\ \\\\ \\\'': fontsize=32 [out]
```

or

```
text=\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\ \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\ \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\ \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\ \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\ \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\ \\\\\': fontsize=32 [out]
```

leads to an output of

```
\ \ \ \ \ \: fontsize=32 [out]
```

Comment: Enclose the text value in single quotes and check.

Comment: @Gyan, I edited the question

Comment: Try this monstrosity: `text=\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\ \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\ \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\ \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\ \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\ \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\ \\\\\'`

Comment: @llogan, same result; Why exactly this one? I am also interested in the rules.

Comment: Worked for me in bash shell. I forgot you were in Windows so the escaping may be different for you.